# Proving $\forall A \subset X: f(A)\cap f_{\text{ess}}(X)=\emptyset \implies \mu(A)=0$ & How to think about proofs with essential range.

Tags: measure-theory, intuition

I have had a very quick introduction to measure theory and haven't built up much intuition to guide the proofs I attempt.

I have been struggling for a while now to prove the following [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_range#Properties) which appears on the wiki page of essential range.

For a measurable function $f:(X,\mu)\to \mathbb{C}$ we have the following :

$\forall A \subset X: f(A)\cap f_{\text{ess}}(X)=\emptyset \implies \mu(A)=0$

I'd like help in proving the above lemma, I suspect the above lemma is somewhat elementary but I just can't seem to draw any intuition from the symbolic definition of essential range.

$$
f_{\text{ess}}(X):=\bigg\{\omega \in \mathbb{C}: \forall \epsilon>0, \quad \mu\big(\{x\in X:|f(x)-\omega|<\epsilon\}\big)>0\bigg\}
$$

Also I would really appreciate any advice given on how one typically tackles these types of proofs in measure theory and/or how to think about proofs involving the essential range of a function.

In fact the wikipedia page linked above mentions that the essential range is the smallest closed subset such that the above theorem holds. I think this is a very nice way to conceptualise the essential range.

As always thank you for any input given.

Comment: If you have two sets $A$ and $B$ and would like to show that $\sup A \leq \inf B$, then it is enough to use the definitions of least upper bounds and greatest lower bounds: Every upper bound of $A$ is less than or equal to some lower bound of $B$.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for you comment. I've already proven the inequality of that form. Id like to know how to prove the lemma as to prove the reverse inequality. I.e. something of the form $\inf A \leq \sup B$.

Comment: To prove that $\inf A \leq \sup B$, it is enough to show that every upper bound of $B$ is greater than or equal to every lower bound of $B$.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the first part your comments reference. I think I find the lemma more interesting than what I was using it to prove. Thank you for your comments all the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of essential range is topological in nature. If $f : X \to Y$ where $X$ is a measure space with measure $\mu$ and $Y$ is a topological space, then the essential range of $f$ is the set $$\{y \in Y :\text{ for all open neighborhoods }U\text{ of }y, \mu(f^{-1}(U)) > 0\}$$
The definition you gave makes use of properties of $\Bbb C$ to hide the topological considerations. The idea is that the essential range consists of the values in $Y$ near which $f$ spends a significant amount of time. The topology on $Y$ defines what it means to be "near". The measure on $X$ defines what a significant amount of time is (i.e., the measure is greater than $0$).

A point of $Y$ can be in the range, but not the essential range if $f$ visits the point, but only comes near it on a set of measure $0$. Conversely, the point can be in the essential range, but not in the range if $f$ approaches the point (significantly), but never takes it on.

A simple example is $$ f: [0,1) \to \Bbb R : t \mapsto \begin{cases}t&t > 0\\-1& t = 0\end{cases}$$
The range of $f$ is $\{-1\}\cup(0,1)$, while the essential range is $[0,1]$, including both $0$ and $1$ that are not in the range, but not including $-1$, which is in the range.

---

The key fact which makes your lemma work is that $\Bbb C$ is second-countable. That is, there is some countable basis $\scr B$ for its topology. For example, $\scr B$ could be the set of all balls of rational radius about centers with both coordinates rational.

Now, $f(A) \cap f_{\text{ess}}(X) = \emptyset$  is equivalent to
$$\forall a \in A, f(a) \notin f_{\text{ess}}(X)$$
which is equivalent to
$$\forall a \in A, \exists \epsilon_a > 0, \mu\left(\{x \in X : |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon_a\}\right) = 0$$
or using ball notation,
$$\forall a \in A, \exists \epsilon_a > 0, \mu\left(f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon_a}(f(a))\right) = 0.$$

Since each of the balls $B_{\epsilon_a}(f(a))$ is an open set containing $f(a)$, there is some $U \in \scr B$ with $f(a) \in U \subseteq B_{\epsilon_a}(f(a))$, since $\scr B$ is a basis. Note that $$\mu(f^{-1}(U)) \le \mu(f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon_a}(f(a)))) = 0.$$ For each $a \in A$, choose such a $U$ and let $B$ be the collection of all of them. Since $B \subseteq \scr B$, it has to be countable.

So $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A)) \subseteq f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{U \in B}U\right)= \bigcup_{U \in B}f^{-1}(U)$ and thus
$$\mu(A) \le \mu\left(\bigcup_{U \in B}f^{-1}(U)\right) \le \sum_{U \in B}\mu\left(f^{-1}(U)\right) = \sum_{U \in B} 0 = 0$$